Joint measurability in quantum mechanics
Two POVMs $E= \{E_i\}$ and $F= \{F_j\}$ are said to be jointly measurable if there exists a POVM $G= \{G_{ij}\}$ such that $$E_i=\sum_j G_{ij}\quad  \text{and}\quad F_j =\sum_i G_{ij}$$
From this definition it is shown that commutativity is necessary for two PVMs to be jointly measurable.
So does this definition mean that two observables are jointly measurable if there always exist a joint probability distribution whose marginal distributions are equal to individual observed probability distributions?
If the above definition is true, then can we say that momentum and position whose probability distribution for a given state is related by Fourier transform are not jointly measurable since there doesn't always exist a joint probability distribution for any two marginal distributions that are related by a Fourier transform?

IIRC, if at least one of the observables is sharp, then the observables are jointly measurable iff they commute. Since $X,P$ are both sharp, they are not jointly measurable.

Two observables are jointly measurable if there always exist a joint probability distribution whose marginal distributions are equal to individual observed probability distributions.
This is indeed the definition of compatible observable described in terms of POVMs (including the PVM case).
In case of PVMs that is equivalent to saying that two projectors of the respective  two PVMs commute.
The PVMs of position and momentum do not commute so that there is no PVM (or POVM) which defines them as marginals.

There is no such connection in general. To study that connection you need a theory about the post measurement state. In case of PVMs, if you accept the projection postulate, then joint measurability reproduces the same result as the one of standard conditional probability. If you use POVMs or you do not use the projection postulate with PVMs, the relation is not given.
